# Twig : Entity was not found

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

I create a new application with existant datas.

I use sonatadminbundle to list a datagrid of objects "Formule"
In my object "Formule" i have a relation to object "Contact".
In my list in need to display this relation. But i know there is some Contact has deleted in the past. I want to make this in the template of my row datagrid :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field%}
    {% if object.getContact.name is defined  %}
        {{ object.getContact.name }} //EntityWasNotFound
    {% else %}
        This contact was deleted in the past
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

So this error return me EntityWasNotFound exception in the line or the Contact was deleted. I don't know to detect if there is a contact. I use "is not null", "defined", "empty"... and nothing it's ok :(

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a common problem when you use softdeleteable or if you have a legacy db with some integrity problems(ids without related row). In this case the proxy of entity is created fine(with its id) but when you get something else the proxy tries to fetch the real entity and fails throwing this exception

you can proceed in more than one way but in sonata admin is a bit more difficult so my suggestion is to create a method that handles the exception then having a further information

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException;

....

public function hasContact()
{
    try {
        $ret = parent::getParent();
        if (isset($ret) && $ret->getName()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

of course you can move this out of the entity and create a twig extension for it (**NOT TESTED**)

```
public function isEntityDefined($entity = null)
{
    if($entity instanceof \Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy){
        try {
            $entity->__load();        
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException $e) {
            $entity = null;
        }
    }
    return isset($entity);
}
```

another approach is to disable softdeleteable using the following code in your controller

```
 $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
```

of course in this way yuo need to look into deletedAt property to check if the entity isn't deleted

Comment: Thank you, it's ok for me :)

Comment: The function "isEntityDefined" was excatly what I am looking for... But how did you integrate this function in sonata admin?

Comment: Done also in sonata admin, easiest way is to define a twig extension for that and use it in your custom cell templates

Comment: I have created an twig extension containing the isEntityDefined-functionallity... but it won't work. The new twig function should deliver the object.location as $entity?

Comment: Ahh I got it.. works now... Great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should purge your database first and remove all orphans rows in the affected table.
It looks like that there's a join table with a record that is pointing to inexistent foreign one. I don't think you can detect this in the code, because, according to Doctrine there's a record, but as matter of fact your database won't return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your database engine is **InnoDB**.

I just had this problem today, the hosting of one of our clients only had the **MyISAM** Engine, which means the foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`were not working. When the client deleted a related entity (category in our case) we started getting the error message **Entity was not found.** when accessing the relation.

If this is the case, change the database engine to **InnoDB** and update the shema using the console.

Also make sure you set entries that have no relation to **NULL** not zero.